# USB-C Travel Hub: Ethernet port not working on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: lenovo, ethernet, thinkpad

I have a T480s with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. My USB-C Travel Hub from Lenovo (see https://download.lenovo.com/pccbbs/options_iso/usbc_travel_hub_qsg_sp40m60799_en.pdf) nicely works for the HDMI monitor and another USB device. However, the Ethernet port does not work. I can neither shift the PCI or USB Ethernet toggle to the right in Settings > Network. It says: "Cable unplugged". When I plug the cable directly into the laptops RJ45 port, it works.

Do I need to install additional drivers, or might the device be broken?

Btw, I found the firmware for Windows, but there doesn't seem to be one for Linux. Is there a generic one maybe? https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/downloads/ds542615